# Print multiple lines without space between lines

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of lines (from a text file) to be printed in terminal. This is the format I like (without empty lines between printed lines):

```
>>> print("line \n" * 5)
line 
line 
line 
line 
line
```

This is how it looks (a line with text, an empty line, etc.):

```
>>> for x in range(0, 5): print "line \n"
... 
line 

line 

line 

line 

line
```

Any idea why it's working in this way and how to print my list of lines without empty lines between them?

UPDATE (this is where I want to get rid of empty lines):

```
with open(FILE, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        print line
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually **due to the way you're reading the file**.  If you've done something like

```
with open(FILE) as f:
    data = f.readlines()
```

Then the `data` will be a list of lines which retain the end of line character.  If you don't want the end of line character, use this instead:

```
with open(FILE) as f:
    data = f.read().splitlines()
```

If you don't want to change the way that you read the data into a list, then concatenate and print the lines like this instead:

```
print ''.join(data)
```

To answer the literal question, if you have a string with a newline, and you want to suppress the newline generated by the print statement, the way to do that in Python 2 is by using a trailing comma on the print statement:

```
with open(FILE) as f:
    for line in f:
        print line,
```

But note, that's not really necessary to iterate line by line like that.  You may as well just print the data directly:

```
with open(FILE) as f:
    print f.read()
```

Comment: Though this does solve the OP's issue, I have to point out it doesn't answer the stated problem - how not to print extra newlines on strings ending with it.

Comment: @Todor  Added a final section to the answer to address the literal question.

Answer (score 1):

When using a for loop you can remove "\n" as follows

```
for x in range(0, 5): print "line"
```

Answer (score 1):

The print command implicitly adds a new line feed `\n` in the output display. Remove the `\n` to avoid printing blank lines in the looping structure.

Answer (score 1):

`print` adds a trailing newline by default. You can disable it as follows:

```
from __future__ import print_function  # only needed for python 2
print("string", end="")
```

Answer (score 1):

By default `print` adds a newline, and your strings also have it; you have two possible solutions.

Either override this behaviour, setting the string to be put to empty:

```
# python 3.*
for x in range(0, 5): print("line \n", end="")
```

And

```
# python 2.*
from __future__ import print_function  # to use py3 print in py2
for x in range(0, 5): print("line \n", end="")
```

Alternatively, if you don't have full control over the lines - some may have the newlines, other - not, trim any newline endings and leave the default behaviour:

```
for x in range(0, 5): print("line \n".rstrip("\n").rstrip("\r"))  # takes care of also Windows line ending, just in case
```

Answer (score 0):

A standard call to the print function will add a newline automatically so you can either remove the `\n` from your existing line(s), *if the lines come from an external file use `line.strip()`*, or tell print not to add the newline with: `print(line, end='')`

This will work for Python3 or for 2.7 with `from __future__ import print_function` as the first code line.